# FastAPI docker app on Azure app service throws a System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, azure-web-app-service, supabase-database

I have a FastAPI + SQLAlchemy (PostgreSQL Supabase) app deployed on Azure App services via a docker container. The service is configured to stay alive so there is no cold start problem.

Every now and then the following error is seen in the logs and the app hangs (APIs non-responsive and do not timeout/return a response) at the same time.
There does not seem to be definitive pattern to when this issue occurs.

Unable to find any relevant documentation or similar issues online. Anyone else come across this issue and if so what did you do to resolve it.

*Failed to forward request to http://1xx.xx.xx.2:8000. Encountered a System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException exception after 300021.816ms with message: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 300 seconds elapsing.. Check application logs to verify the application is properly handling HTTP traffic.*

Tried optimising the DB

- increased the configuration
- using Supabase provided pooler service
- caching DB results to reduce DB calls

Increased the config of the App Service

----- adding code snippet----

In terms of code

```
# db.py

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = os.environ["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL"]
def get_engine():
    return create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, pool_pre_ping=True)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(
    autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=get_engine())


# In main.py 

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
        db.commit()
    except:
        # if any kind of exception occurs, rollback transaction
        db.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        db.close()

#And then in the routes I pass the session as Depends

def test_auth0(token=Depends(token_auth_scheme), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
```

Comment: could you please share the code you tried?

Comment: In addition to sharing the code, you should also increase logging and monitoring to figure out what exactly is causing a timeout. The error message you included only tells us that something is taking a long time to execute (most probably waiting for something) in your code.

Comment: It does not appear to be code specific i.e the error occurs randomly all throughout but only when the DB is involved. Which is why I suspect it something to do with Python and SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Are you using azure-postgresql db?

Comment: @Aswin not using Azure. The DB is in Supabase.

Comment: Edited the Question with relevant tags

Answer (score 0):

I followed this reference to push FastApi with PostgreSQL to the [Docker](https://medium.com/@kevinkoech265/dockerizing-fastapi-and-postgresql-effortless-containerization-a-step-by-step-guide-68b962c3e7eb).

[image]

- To run the FastApi on Azure web app service, the PostgreSQL should be converted to Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Single [Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/connect-python).
- Create an Azure Database for PostgreSQL single server using  [Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/quickstart-create-server-database-portal).
- - The sample Flask code below connects to a PostgreSQL database and provides two routes:  `/insert_data`  for inserting data into the database and  `/read_data`  for reading data from the database.

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import os
import psycopg2

app = Flask(__name__)

# Replace these values with your Azure Database for PostgreSQL connection details
host = "<server-name>"
user = "<admin-username>"
port =  5432
dbname =   "<admin-password>"
password = "Ra@80muravi"
sslmode = "require"


conn_string = f"host={host} user={user} port={port} dbname={dbname} password={password} sslmode={sslmode}"

# Route to insert data
@app.route("/insert_data")
def insert_data():
    try:
        # Establish a new connection
        conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
        print("Connection established for /insert_data")

        # Create a cursor object
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Drop previous table of the same name if it exists
        cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inventory;")
        print("Finished dropping table (if existed)")

        # Create a table
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE inventory (id serial PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50), quantity INTEGER);")
        print("Finished creating table")

        # Insert some data into the table
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO inventory (name, quantity) VALUES (%s, %s);", ("banana", 150))
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO inventory (name, quantity) VALUES (%s, %s);", ("orange", 154))
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO inventory (name, quantity) VALUES (%s, %s);", ("apple", 100))
        print("Inserted 3 rows of data")

        # Commit the changes
        conn.commit()

        return jsonify({"message": "Data inserted successfully"})
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)})
    finally:
        # Close the cursor and connection
        if not cursor.closed:
            cursor.close()
        if not conn.closed:
            conn.close()
            print("Connection closed for /insert_data")

# Route to read data
@app.route("/read_data")
def read_data():
    try:
        # Establish a new connection
        conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
        print("Connection established for /read_data")

        # Create a cursor object
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Fetch all rows from the table
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM inventory;")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        # Print all rows
        data = [{"id": row[0], "name": row[1], "quantity": row[2]} for row in rows]

        return jsonify({"data": data})
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)})
    finally:
        # Close the cursor and connection
        if not cursor.closed:
            cursor.close()
        if not conn.closed:
            conn.close()
            print("Connection closed for /read_data")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

- Follow this reference  [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-containerize-simple-web-app-for-app-service?tabs=web-app-fastapi)  to deploy a FastAPI web app as a container in Azure App Service.